# Find duplicated columns in file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I can search a file for unique columns and it works with one file.  But how do I search multiple files?

```
awk -F"|&" 'x[$1]++ { print $1 " is duplicated"}'  /home/pi/tmpdata/f1.txt
```

This howeever does not bring back the correct duplicates.  Looks like it is just reading the file and printing everything.
    awk -F"|&" 'x[$1]++ { print $1 " is duplicated"}'  /home/pi/tmpdata/*.txt

Comment: Do you mean duplicated _rows_, based on a particular column? What does the data look like?

Comment: sorry I meant duplicate columns.  The columns are separated by `|&` and I need to check the first column in a number of files.  I assumed that `/home/pi/tmpdata/*.txt` would work. but it does not.

Comment: your code works for me with some dummy input files, please provide your input files or relevant parts of it to reproduce your issue.

Comment: input data looks like `mike52|&52|&street` on each line with of course different usernames.

Comment: Your code does not look across columns, which makes me a bit confused as to what you'd want to do. A column runs across multiple rows, and your code currently detects duplicated _rows_. What do you mean (in your comment) with "check the 1st column in a number of files"? Do you want to check the contents of the 1st column between files? Could you give an example?

Comment: `echo "mike52|&52|&street" > f1; cp f1 f2; awk -F"|&" 'x[$1]++ { print $1 " is duplicated"}' f*;` outputs `mike52| is duplicated`. So what is the problem?

Comment: Your field separator is invalid: you'll need to escape the pipe character: `awk -F'\\|&' ...`